# $\kappa\otimes\kappa=\kappa\implies\lambda\otimes\kappa=max\{\lambda,\kappa\}$

Tags: cardinals, ordinals

I was curious about cardinal and ordinal numbers so I read a bit about them in Kunens set theory book. At some point he proves that if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal number, then $\kappa\otimes\kappa=\kappa$ (cardinal multiplication) and he states as a corollary that if $\lambda,\kappa$ are infinite cardinals, then $\lambda\oplus\kappa =\lambda\otimes\kappa=max\{\lambda,\kappa\}$. But I don't understand if this follows.

Comment: What are $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ in context?

Comment: Does he assume the axiom of choice to ensure $\max\{\lambda,\,\kappa\}$ exists?

Comment: @J.G.: Throughout the book Ken works in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda\le\kappa$, $\lambda\otimes\kappa\color{blue}{\le}\kappa\otimes\kappa=\kappa=\max\{\lambda,\,\kappa\}$, where the $\color{blue}{\le}$ follows from the fact that, if $f$ bijects a size-$\lambda$ set $L$ into a size-$\kappa$ set $K$, $(x,\,y)\mapsto(f(x),\,y)$ similarly injects $L\times K$ into $K^2$. Similarly, if $\kappa<\lambda$ then $\lambda\otimes\kappa=\kappa\otimes\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\,\lambda\}=\max\{\lambda,\,\kappa\}$. You can handle addition in a similar way if you've proven $\kappa\oplus\kappa=\kappa$ for all transfinite $\kappa$.

Comment: Oh, I see, and since $\lambda \otimes \kappa=\vert \lambda \times \kappa \vert \ge \vert \kappa\vert=\kappa$ and $\lambda \otimes \kappa=\vert \lambda \times \kappa \vert \ge \vert \lambda\vert=\lambda$ then $\lambda \otimes \kappa=\vert \lambda \times \kappa \vert \ge max(\lambda,\kappa)$ and we have equality